# Adding a form input that is excluded from params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I've got a form with some check_box_tags. Some of these checkboxes do not belong to the model and need to be removed from the params hash. I know i can use the exclude method, but the problem is that these fields have dynamic ids that I can't know in advance.

My question is:

Is there a way of excluding a form field so it doesn't enter the params hash in the first place?

Many thanks!
Uri

Comment: u will have to place it out of the form so that they arent submitted in the context of the object to which the form belongs. Anyway, input fields like checkboxes, radio buttons, text fields, areas are going to be submitted. Alternately, u can add a common class to these fields and remove them using exclude.

Comment: Are you using Rails 4? Because with [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) you can create a whitelist of attributes for your params hash. Everything not on the whitelist will be deleted from the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you submit a form to a controller and the input fields have a name, those K:V pairs will be added to the params request assuming they are white listed by your strong parameters (rails4 only). Your best option would be to use JavaScript. Something like this would filter those fields based on class, data attr, or any other parameter you would like to filter by:

```
$('.new_resource_form').onSubmit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.fields_for_removal').remove();
    $(this).submit();
});
```